# AudioQueueLevelMeterState from AVPlayer object

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, avplayer, audioqueueservices

Is it possible to extract queue's from AVPlayer somehow, because from a queue is possible to extract objects like AudioQueueLevelMeterState, or information about channel numbers, sublevel meters to draw some nice animation on the scene while sound is playing, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

`AVPlayer` is at a higher level than `AudioQueue`. `AudioQueueLevelMeterState` only offers `mPeakPower` and `mAveragePower`.

If you want detailed values for a nice animation, you'll need to go down to the actual float or integer values of the captured audio buffers themselves.